# Can't call function in service

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Using AngularJS 1.7.0 with TypeScript

I have a directive:

```
namespace Test.CustomerService.CustomerCard {
    import AnotherService = Test.AnotherService;
    angular.module('Test')
        .directive('timelineItem', ['$rootScope', ($rootScope) => {
                return {
                    link(scope, element, attr) {
                        element.on('click', (anotherService: AnotherService) => {
                            console.log(anotherService);
                            console.log(anotherService.getWelcomeMessage());

                        });
                    }
                };
        }]);
}
```

And a service:

```
    namespace Test {

        export class AnotherService {
            constructor(
            ) {
                console.log('something');
            }

            public getWelcomeMessage(): String {
                console.log('something');
                // Enjoy auto-completion and type safety :)
                return 'Welcome from AnotherService, ';
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on the on the element with the directive on it I get this in the console:

> Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, target: h3, currentTarget: div.activity-header, …}
>
> Uncaught TypeError: anotherService.getWelcomeMessage is not a function

But in Visual Studio when I follow the definition of the function `console.log(anotherService.getWelcomeMessage());` in the directive it takes me to the function in the service.

Comment: First argument of click handler is Event object, not instance of AnotherService

Comment: Is there a way to pass in the AnotherService instance?

Comment: did you register AnotherService as angularjs service, i mean `angular.module('Test').service('name', function () { })

Comment: You should inject `AnotherService` in your directive, not in your element handle click function.

Comment: Hmhm, but that results in > `Unknown provider: anotherServiceProvider <- anotherService <- timelineItemDirective` Like Praveen said, I think I need to register the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, May be it'll help you.

```
namespace Test.CustomerService.CustomerCard {
import AnotherService = Test.AnotherService;
angular.module('Test')
    .directive('timelineItem', ['$rootScope', 'AnotherServiceProvider' ($rootScope, AnotherServiceProvider) => {
            let anotherService = AnotherServiceProvider.$get();
            return {
                link(scope, element, attr) {
                    element.on('click', (anotherService: AnotherService) => {
                        console.log(anotherService);
                        console.log(anotherService.getWelcomeMessage());

                    });
                }
            };
    }]);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. Results in a `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider` > `Unknown provider: AnotherServiceProvider <- AnotherService <- timelineItemDirective`